# retrieval from json gives errors in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to retrieve a row from the server.

I am getting the following error.

**Log**

```
E/log_tag(1948): connection success [sendernumber=9040307070]
E/log_tag(1948): result ?9545357470[{"TaskId":"1"},{"TaskId":"2"}]
E/log_tag(1948): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 9040307070 of type java.lang.Long cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

**JSON Code**

```
     String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mydomainname.org/task/senttask.php");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair>  nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sendernumber",name.toString()));
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sendernumber","9595959595"));
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.e("log_tag", "connection success "+nameValuePairs);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    try
    {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,HTTP.UTF_8),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
          Log.e("log_tag", "result "+result.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
           Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    try
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
          String s="",s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
          Log.w("Lengh",""+jArray.length());
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                  s=json_data.getString("TaskId");

                   Log.e("taskid from server","s");

            }



    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**Table on the server**

```
 TaskId int primary key
 sendernumber varchar(100)
```

Comment: it seems you are not getting response json array properly!! please check and post what response you are getting

Comment: I am getting only that much of error logs

Comment: you are getting response 9545357470[{"TaskId":"1"},{"TaskId":"2"}] why the data 9545357470 is attached with yours response?? did you investigate for that?

Comment: Indeed, the reponse you get is not valid JSON, therefore you cannot parse it like JSON. Please investigate the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to simply work, use `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result.substring(result.indexOf("[")));` instead of `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);`

However, something seems wrong with your webservice. It's returning `9545357470[{"TaskId":"1"},{"TaskId":"2"}]` and that really should just be `[{"TaskId":"1"},{"TaskId":"2"}]`. So I'm not sure what exactly is happening there when you are trying to create your json array to send it as a response, but the best solution would be to fix that instead of the code that you have here.